# React Native's useNavigation hook inside of a custom hook?

Tags: react-hooks, react-navigation, expo

Im using React Navigation's `useNavigation` hook:

In MyComponent.js:

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const MyComponent = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const handleNav = () => {
        navigation.navigate("about");
    };
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNav}>
            <Text>About</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Is there a way to move this functionality to a custom hook? I tried the following:

In useCustomNav.js:

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const useCustomNav = ({ to }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  navigation.navigate(to);
  return null;
};

export default useCustomNav;
```

In MyComponent.js:

```js
import useCustomNav from './useCustomNav';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const handleNav = () => {
        useCustomNav("about");
    };
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNav}>
            <Text>About</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Im getting an error:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I understand that this is happening as `useNavigation` is 'hidden' within a function call but not how to fix it.

The reason Im trying to do this is I'm sharing code between a React Native and React Native Web project but I need to do routing differently. Expo can target different platforms with different file names eg `useCustomNav.native.js` for native and `useCustomNav.web.js` for the web. So I need to have a swappable function for routing for the different platforms. I cant have the `useNavigation` hook in `MyComponent` as it's only going to be used for native, it will error for web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return a function from the custom navigator hook to let you navigate to the route that you want.

```js
const useCustomNav = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const goTo = to => navigation.navigate(to);

  return {goTo};
};
```

And use it like:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const navigator = useCustomNav();

    const handleNav = () => {
        navigator.goTo("about");
    };

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNav}>
            <Text>About</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```